# How to access the traditional Boot Order BIOS menu on a Dell G3

Tags: boot, bios, dell-g3

I just received a new `Dell G3` and am busy making the most of it (i.e. installing *Linux* ..) But where is the Boot Device Order menu?  The one that will let you move the following around:

- HDD/SSD drives
- USB Devices
- Network Boot devices

(Note: clicking on "Windows Boot Manager" does not change any behavior)

[image]

Already done:

- disabled `Secure Boot`
- disabled `Deployed` mode for `Secure Mode`

Here is the result of `View` . It does not necessarily help me ..

[image]

What about `Legacy External Devices` ? It took some doing to even be permitted to select it.. But *still* we do not see the traditional *Boot Order*

[image]

So how do I get the `Boot Order` screen on the `BIOS` of this `Dell G3` laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the Boot Order was ready to show its face.  I needed to do a hard shutdown / restart apparently.  Then it did show up